# Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am createing MvvmCross Xamarin Application. Everything were working great untill today. I dont know what happens but all the time I am getting build error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources
>   AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat

I am totally wasted. I spent whole day reading google and nothing helped. Does someone faced similar problem ?

Comment: This happens when you install which package?

Comment: It happend while i am trying to build

Comment: Try cleaning your project and remove the packages folder, see if that helps

Comment: What fixed it for us was to NOT use the Components feature from Xamarin and only reference NuGet packages. The Components abstraction is a mess and Xamarin's poor testing procedures allow broken features to released all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Try to open .csproj and manually remove all "Import" tags that refer to "unwanted" references.
Reload project into VS and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this.

1. Close visual studio and msbuild.exe (you can find it at task manager)
2. Delete all your packages.
3. Open again visual studio
4. Right-click in your Android project's `References`
5. Click `Manage NuGet Packages`
6. Click `Restore packages`

That's what works for me. But it's really frustrating that for a simple work as package addition I have to lose about 10 minutes of my life.